# Securing Sensitive Information in ASP.NET C# Web.config

Tags: iis, sharepoint, web-config, remote-desktop

My current web.config has information like `validationKey` and `decrytionKey` opened for viewing in my development environment.

I would like to hide the sensitive information.

Does changing any of these settings secures it from exposure?

These are my current settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to encrypt the web config file and hide sensitive information.

There is a new security feature in ASP.NET 2.0. Any configuration section in the Web.config file can be encrypted. This can be done by manually running the tool aspnet_regiis or programming. If you have direct access to your web server, you can do this by running the following command line:

```
cd  %windows%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber  

aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/SampleApplication" –prov RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider 

-pd section
```

Decrypt the configuration section. This parameter takes the following optional parameters:

· -app virtualPath specifies that the level should be decrypted at the level of the include path.

· -location subPath Specifies the subdirectory to decrypt.

· -pkm specifies that Machine.config should be decrypted instead of the Web.config file.

-pdf section webApplicationDirectory
Decrypts the specified configuration section of the Web.config file in the specified physical (non-virtual) directory.

-pe section
Encrypts the specified configuration section. This parameter takes the following optional modifiers:

• -prov provider specifies the encryption provider to use.

· -app virtualPath specifies that encryption should be done at the level of the include path.

· -location subPath specifies the subdirectory to be encrypted.

· -pkm specifies that Machine.config should be encrypted instead of the Web.config file.

-pef section webApplicationDirectory
Encrypts the specified configuration section of the Web.config file in the specified physical (non-virtual) directory.

If you are using a virtual host or the like that does not have access to the physical server, you can still programmatically encrypt the connection string.

```
Configuration config =Configuration.GetWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath); 
ConfigurationSection section =config.Sections["connectionStrings"]; 
section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider");; 
config.Update ();
```

Profiles that encrypt connection string values with protected configurations now do not display the connection strings in clear text, but instead store them in encrypted form, as shown in the following example:

[image: Protected configuration]

You can refer to the relevant documents I am looking for.
[Protecting Connection Strings and Other Configuration Information (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/advanced-data-access-scenarios/protecting-connection-strings-and-other-configuration-information-cs)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Can I encrypt <machineKey> with this as well?

Comment: You can try it.